# Getting null response with response code 500 in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm implementing an app where I've a user profile that I want to edit so I get all the user input as strings and send them to the server using retrofit 2, I tried the code many times only 1 out of 100 try works fine and the rest I get a null response with response code 500

here you can see my code :

this is the interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("edit/profile")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AuthModel> editProfile (@Field("api_token") String api_token,
                                   @Field("profilePic") String profilePic,
                                 @Field("name") String name,
                                 @Field("email") String email,
                                 @Field("phoneNo") String phoneNo,
                                 @Field("state") String state,
                                 @Field("city") String city,
                                 @Field("age") String age,
                                 @Field("sex") String sex,
                                 @Field("lastBooking") String lastBooking,
                                 @Field("hostel") String hostel,
                                 @Field("roomNumber") String roomNumber,
                                 @Field("status") String status);
}
```

this is the AuthModel

```
public class AuthModel {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("api_token")
    private String api_token;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("api_token_status")
    private String api_token_status;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;


    public String getApi_token() {
        return api_token;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getApi_token_status() {
        return api_token_status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

this is the ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.kyz.com/api/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

this is the method where I make the request

```
public void editProfileRequest (final Context context, String api_token, String profilePic, String name, String email, String phoneNo, String state,
                                String city, String age, String sex, String lastBooking, String hostel, String roomNumber, String status) {

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<AuthModel> call = apiInterface.editProfile(api_token, profilePic, name, email, phoneNo, state, city, age, sex,
            lastBooking, hostel, roomNumber, status);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AuthModel> call, Response<AuthModel> response) {
            AuthModel result = response.body();
            if(result != null) {
                String status = result.getStatus();
                String msg = result.getMessage();
                if(status.equals("true")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, response.errorBody().string() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("errorBody", response.errorBody().string());
                    Log.v("respCode", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AuthModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

last thing I want to share with you is the response.errorBody()

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry &#039;barsoum@email.com&#039; for key &#039;users_email_unique&#039; (SQL: update `users` set `name` = Barsoum, `email` = barsoum@email.com, `city` = Asyut, `bloodType` = B+, `hospital` = St Louis, `roomNumber` = 555, `numOfPackets` = 6, `status` = Preparing for Surgery, `updated_at` = 2019-03-06 22:02:37 where `id` = 30) in file /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
Stack trace:
  1. Illuminate\Database\QueryException-&gt;() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
  2. PDOException-&gt;() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:483
  3. PDOStatement-&gt;execute() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:483
  4. Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;Illuminate\Database\{closure}() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
  5. Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;runQueryCallback() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
  6. Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;run() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:490
  7. Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;affectingStatement() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:423
  8. Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;update() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2508
  9. Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder-&gt;update() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:780
 10. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder-&gt;update() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:693
 11. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;performUpdate() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:608
 12. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;save() /home/keesbdco/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ProfileController.php:57
 13. App\Http\Controllers\Api\ProfileController-&gt;edit() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
 14. call_user_func_array() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
 15. Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
 16. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:212
 17. Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:169
 18. Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:665
 19. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
 20. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/keesbdco/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/typeapi.php:19
 21. App\Http\Middleware\typeapi-&gt;handle() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
 22. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
 23. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
 24. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle() /home/keesbdco/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/I
```

please help me to solve this issue I don't think it's a serverside bug because  1% of my tries works fine and 99% I get this issue. please help, Thanks

Comment: isn't the error message you get from the server specific clear? You are using an e-mail that is already used, and you can't have double e-mails adresses as the key. Try a different one...

Comment: excuse i'm not the one implementing the serverside code and I've no idea about its framework. anyway thank you so much I'll get back to the backend developer

Answer (score 0):

Response code `500` is `Internal Server Error`, meaning something is wrong on its side.

See [this link](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/) for reference on HTTP resonse status codes.